# How can I convert my obj C code to swift code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, translate

I started working on iOS with Swift only and have no idea about objective C, could anyone help me in converting this code written in objective C to Swift 4.

```
UIImageView *iconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 50)];
iconView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my-icon-image"];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 50)];
label.text = @"test";
[iconView addSubview:label];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.bounds.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[iconView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *icon = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng);
marker.title = @"my title";
marker.icon = icon;

marker.map = mapView;
```

Also if anyone knows a free translater kindly share it.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
//  Converted to Swift 5.2 by Swiftify v5.2.18740 - https://swiftify.com/
let iconView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 50))
iconView.image = UIImage(named: "my-icon-image")

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 50))
label.text = "test"
iconView.addSubview(label)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.bounds.size, _: false, _: UIScreen.main.scale)
if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    iconView.layer.render(in: context)
}
let icon = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)
marker.title = "my title"
marker.icon = icon
```

You can use https://swiftify.com/#/converter/code/ for small chunk of code